# get_the_terms child terms for current post/custom post only

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, single, terms

Inside a Post **/** Custom Post type loop, I am trying to get child terms selected on the edit screen of that post/custom post.

For Example:

1. **Zoologist ( Parent )**

   - Pre Zoologist
   - Post Zoologist

Now if for any specific post **/** custom post if users selected all of above taxonomies including *Zoologist (Parent)*, *Pre Zoologist*, *Post Zoologist*.

Using **get_the_terms** function i only want to get child taxomony, in this case *Pre Zoologist*, *Post Zoologist*.

I tried this code but it is not working:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'custom_taxonomy' );

  foreach ( $terms as $term ){
  if ( $term->parent == 0 ) {
    echo '<div class="parent '.$term->slug.'">' . $term->name . '</div>';
  }

}
```

Please let me know where am I making a mistake.

Comment: Your code is only displaying terms without carents. you want the Opposite. Change `==` to `!==`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for guiding me. Can you please post it as an answer so that others can get help.